# Microsoft Edge iframe in dropdown closes menu on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a multi-tab dropdown menu. One tab reveals a static image (the cover of the current issue of a journal) and next to it I have an iframe that embeds a formatted RSS feed with the contents of the issue.

This works well on all browsers except Edge, where the menu appears, but if you mouse over the iframe, the menu closes, in much the same way as if you'd moved the mouse off the menu.

I can keep the menu open by navigating around the iframe, but as soon as I enter the iframe, the image closes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you provide us some example?

Comment: go to www.rigaku.com and pull down the Journal menu. Then move the mouse around inside the dropdown. If you skate across the top and down the left side where the image is, everything is fine, but if you go across the text on the right, the menu collapses.